# Why does Web Animation API reverse() cause my animation to jump?

Tags: javascript, css, web-animations

[Docs everywhere](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/reverse) say that calling `reverse()` while animation is playing is the same as setting `playbackRate` to -1, but my animation jumps like crazy  when `reverse()` is used. `playbackRate` works fine. I would really like to use `reverse()` because it is state-independent but I'm afraid I don't understand it.

I have a small example of a rotating square on codesandbox here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/small-browser-1bkdt?file=/src/index.js

Am I doing something wrong or is `reverse()` not so simple?

**UPDATE**:

- It might be a be Codesandbox bug, since [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tobpf841/) by @Kaiido works fine.
- I'm using Firefox 75.0 and MacOS. Chrome seems to work fine.

Comment: It looks find in Chrome for me. Smooth. I don't see any jumping.

Comment: @will Oh my. I was using Firefox. I checked and it actually works fine in Chrome...

Comment: Weird...  can reproduce sometimes in the codesandbox, but not in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tobpf841/) nor in StackSnippets... (FF 75 & 77 on macOs)

Comment: @Kaiido Wow, it indeed works fine in the fiddle you linked to. Perhaps it is some weird Codesandbox bug.

Comment: Yeah, hard to tell with all the dependencies that are being injected. Could also be an FF bug. But do you face it in your own environment?

Comment: @Kaiido So far I am just exploring and playing around with the API so can't tell whether it is going to work properly.

Comment: Looks smooth to me in Firefox, too. Which version are you using, @jlkiri?

Comment: @D.Pardal 75.0 macOS

Comment: I'm using 76.0b8 on Windows.

Comment: I noticed that even the fiddle by @Kaiido doesn't work properly in latest Safari though...

Comment: Firefox developer and spec editor here. I can't reproduce on Firefox 77 on Windows. If you can reproduce consistently, would you mind filing a bug at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org?

In terms of the spec though, using `reverse()` is definitely correct. On the contrary setting `playbackRate` can cause jumps (while `updatePlaybackRate()` should not).

Comment: @brianskold Thank you for checking. I was told by codesandbox team that disabling "Infinite Loop Protection" in sandbox.config.js might help. Doing that and forking the project helped me both on 75, 76 and 77. So, I don't think this is a Firefox bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is clear from [this codesandbox issue](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/4000), jumpy behaviour can be solved with disabling "Infinite loop protection" in `sandbox.config.json`. I also had to fork the project before it started to work perfectly fine. This is likely not a problem with Firefox.